# JavaScript работа с localStorage, добавление и удаление

Tags: javascript, localstorage

На данный момент пытаюсь сделать функционал для оставления и просмотра отзывов о продуктах.
Сейчас смог реализовать только поле для ввода названия продукта, текстовое поле для самого отзыва и кнопку "Добавить отзыв", которая сохраняет отзыв о продукте в LocalStorage (возможно есть ошибки).

Но возникли проблемы со следующим функционалом:

1. Показывает список всех продуктов, о которых были оставлены отзывы.
2. При клике на название продукта отображается список всех отзывов по этому продукту.
3. Возможность удаления отзыва (при нажатии на кнопку "Удалить" рядом с отзывом, данный отзыв удаляется из LocalStorage).
   HTML

```
 <div class="reviews-block container">
            <h1 class="title">Страница отзывов</h1>
            <div class="reviews-box">
                <div class="items" id="item-reviews">
                    <!-- ОТОБРАЖЕНИЕ ОТЗЫВОВ-->
                </div>
                <form class="reviews-form">
                    <h3>Наименование товара</h3>
                    <input id="product-name" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Название продукта">
                    <h3>Ваш отзыв о товаре</h3>
                    <input id="feedback" contenteditable=true class="input" type="text" placeholder="Ваш отзыв">
                    <button id="add-btn" class="form-btn" type="submit">Добавить отзыв</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
let comments = [];
loadComments();

const addBtn = document.getElementById('add-btn');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   
    let commentName = document.getElementById('product-name');
    let commentBody = document.getElementById('feedback');

    let comment = {
        name : commentName.value,
        body : commentBody.value,
    }

    commentName.value = '';
    commentBody.value = '';
    
    comments.push(comment);

    localStorage.setItem('comments', JSON.stringify(comments));

    showComments();
})



function loadComments(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('comments')) comments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('comments'));
    showComments();
}

function showComments (){
    let commentField = document.getElementById('item-reviews');
    let out = '';
    comments.forEach(function(item){
        out += `<p class="name" role="alert">${item.name}</p>`;
        out += `<p class="comment" role="alert">${item.body}</p>`;
    });
    commentField.innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: Такие отзывы можно посмотреть только на том компе - на котором их написали...

Comment: Судя по коду и вопросу - проблемы у вас не в локалсторадж, а в том, что вы не знаете, как отфильтровать данные